# $E(X)>E(Y)$ always imply that $P[X>Y]>0$

Tags: probability, random-variables

*Prove or disprove- "If $E(X)>E(Y)$ then $P[X>Y]>0$*

***What I attempted:-***

I am using contradiction. Suppose $E(X)>E(Y)$. We assume that $P[X>Y]=0$

Now, we have 
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&P[X>Y]=0\\
\Rightarrow & P[(X-Y)>0]=0 \\
\Rightarrow & P[Z>0]=0   \qquad \mbox{where}\quad Z=X-Y
\end{aligned}
\end{equation} 
The last equation imply that \begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
& Z\le 0 \\
\Rightarrow & E(Z)\le 0 \\
\Rightarrow & E(X-Y)\le 0 \\
\Rightarrow & E(X)\le E(Y)\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
which is a contradiction. Therefore we must have $P[X>Y]>0$

Comment: I'd have thought $Z\le 0$.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I did not mind it. Edited accordingly.

Comment: You're swindling yourself by writing $Z\leq 0$ where it should be $P(Z\leq 0)=1$. In fact at that point you have made no real progress, you just transformed the equation into a form that makes you feel comfortable just jumping to the conclusion. But the truth is that you have to use the definition of $E$ at some point. Of course the proof will still be elementary but it will be well-written.

Comment: Thanks Arnaud. The answer provided by Siong Thye Goh has also drew my attention that it should be $P(Z\le 0)=1$. If I am not wrong, I would have proceeded in the following way in order to get $E(Z)\le 0$:-

Comment: \begin{equation} \begin{aligned} E(Z) &=\sum_{z:z\le 0} z P(Z=z)+\sum_{z:z > 0} z P(Z=z) \\  &=\sum_{z:z\le 0} z P(Z=z) \qquad \mbox{[Because, If} \quad z>0, P(Z=z)=0 ]\\ &\le \sum_{z:z\le 0} 0. P(Z=z) \qquad \mbox{[we are summing over all} \quad z \le 0] \\ &=0 \end{aligned} \end{equation}

Comment: Do you know any measure theory? If not, I would very much recommend it! Your claim is very similar to the following claim about functions on $\mathbb{R}$:
$$ \int f(x) dx>\int g(x)dx \iff m(\{x:f(x)>g(x)\})>0 $$
where $m(S)$ gives the length of a set $S \subset \mathbb{R}$  (i.e. $m$ is the Lebesgue measure).

Comment: I have not taken any course yet. However, since you mentioned, I would surely do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems fine.

Just that I would write $$Z \le 0 ~ W.P. 1$$

rather than just $Z \le 0$. We can still have null set that take positive values but it wouldn't influece $E[Z]$.